# SSRS Date Parameter default to last 30 days with Time

Tags: reporting-services

Please could someone help me in getting the below issue sorted?

I am looking for a default Date Parameter (Start Date) to be Last 30 days from Today along with the Time e.g 30 days from now is 24/05/2016 but would like to include Time as well
24/05/2016 07:00:00

I have an expression which only give me Last 30 days date Expression i have is `=DateAdd("d",-29,Today())`

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
=Now.AddDays(-30)
```

**UPDATE:** Default time

```
=Today.AddDays(-30).AddHours(7)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, i tried the above given function, this gives me last 30 days but with the current time. I am looking to restrict the report from last 30 days but with 07:00:00 time.

Comment: Bingo..... Thanks Alejandro... it worked. nice one and thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS Expression to get 30 days back from today using DateAdd function:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -30,Today())
```